# min(), max() and NaN

Tags: python, nan

Is this an expected behaviour or is there something wrong?

```
>>> min((float("nan"), 5))
nan
>>> min((5, float("nan")))
5
>>> max((5, float("nan")))
5
>>> max((float("nan"), 5))
nan
```

I understand that `NaN` is an undefined number, and that an undefined number can be less than or greater than 5. So is it sane that the result of a built-in function depends on the order of its parameters? In my humble opinion all the function calls *should* return NaN.